# AngularJS: Triggering a controller to always change a substate if needed

Tags: angularjs, controller, scope, angular-ui-router

I am using in my angular app UI-Router and i have a certain view which has two sub states under a certain controller. 
Once navigating to "homeState", the controller checks for a certain case and if occurs, it navigates to "homeState.substate1", else "homeState.substate2".
To simplify my issue :

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   if(certainCase) {
     state.go('homeState.substate1');
   }
   else {
     state.go('homeState.substate2');
   }
}]);
```

While considering my above code, to those who are familar with angular it means that when navigating to "/homeState"  the controller is triggered and it will redirect to the correct substate correctly.

The problem occurs in the general flow:

1. we navigate to "homeState" (which redirected correctly to a certain substate)
2. now navigate to "otherState"
3. then, back to "homeState" - 
   **At this point the problem occurs!** the controller no longer triggers my if case and the state
   freezes at "homeState" instead of redirecting to substate1/substate2 (which affects the ui!).

What im trying to do is like forcing the controller to check the case again, though it might be a wrong thinking, i'll be glad if anyone could clarify that.

Comment: How do you transition from otherState back to homeState?

Comment: i use state.go in all cases